# cosine function in c++ without any math function

Tags: c++

I am working on a code to calculate the cosine of a decimal number (in radians). The problem is that I can only get the correct answer when I put a small number. It uses the Taylor series.

```
double coseno(float x)
{
    double t = x;
    double cos= t;
    for ( int a=1; a<20.0; ++a)
    {
        double mult = -x*x/((2*a)*(2*a-1));
        t *= mult;
        cos += t;
    }
    return cos;
}
```

Comment: _"only [works with] small number."_ _"It uses the Taylor series"_ hum... yeah! that's how Taylor series work.

Comment: Note that cosine is periodic. Note that the difference between one *float* and the next greater value can get too large for any trigonometric function value to have any meaning.

Comment: You're doing operations (multiplication, etc) in a way that has large intermediate values.  Reorder the operations to avoid large intermediate values, but still get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

1. You made a mistake. At start you should set t as 1(not x);
2. You forgot about term. If number is too big or small you could simply use some whiles.
   Eventually it works perfectly:

```
#include <math.h> //for M_PI
double coseno(float x){
    while(x<0) x+=2*M_PI;
    while(x>2*M_PI) x-=2*M_PI;
    double t = 1;
    double cos= t;
    for ( int a=1; a<40; ++a)
    {
        double mult = -x*x/((2*a)*(2*a-1));
        t *= mult;
        cos += t;
    }
    return cos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you divide using / the operation is not evaluated with the precision you need. When you use small values the approximation is enough to get the correct result but when you use bigger values you get into an approximation problem.

You repeat the approximation error many times inside the for loop and so you get wronger result as the input increases